# Issue to create domain mapping

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I cant create two domain mapping in two different projects by cloud run service. I am trying create it two hours ago.

Using the console.

Comment: Do you mean Google Cloud Run Custom Domains? You need to provide details. Read this on how to ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes, I am talking about Google Cloud Run Custom Domain. What information do you need? At present the error shows: "ManagedDomain not found".

Comment: Update your question with what you configured in the Cloud Run Console and what you configure in your DNS server. I wrote an article on Cloud Run. Review the section on Create a "Custom Domain and Certificate". Update your question with those details mentioned in my article. https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-run-getting-started-with-python-and-flask/

Comment: Hi, more information about the case. I had in a project two domain mapping configured and working. I needed change the domain mapping from api.domain.com to api.prod.domain.com, so I deleted the current domain mapping and created a new. The new custom domain is experimenting the issue. Also, I created a new google cloud project, built a new container, created a new service but I cant create a domain mapping to the new service. In both cases it shows the same issue.

Comment: Edit your question with the details requested. Follow Stackoverflow's guide on how to ask a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi, I continue with the issue to create Cloud Run domain mapping in two projects.

Comment: Issue fixed. The issue was generated when google cloud run validates the dns record before that provisioning the certificate. I applied some configuration in cloudflare (dns server) and it worked.

Comment: What does "some configuration in cloudfare"... I'm experiening the same issue now, and very little help on the web.